# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Generate different forms based on selected DropDownList option

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to generate (or display hidden maybe?) different type of form depending on the selected Option in a `DropDownList`. What would be the best way to do that?

I have tried having in the base view named `Create` only a `DropDownList` with no forms initially, and script where on change using Ajax to some action in a controller which loads a partial view of the desired form display it as an HTML inside some `<div>` form container.

The problem with this is that I am not getting any client-side validation on the fields of the newly displayed form.

Javascript/jQuery code from `Create` view:

```
let dropDown = $("#SelectedExpenseType")
let expenseFormContainer = $("#ExpenseCreationForm")

dropDown.change(function () {
    let url = dropDown.val();
    //Check if selected option has NULL for Value Attribute
    if ($.isEmptyObject(url)) {
        expenseFormContainer.empty()
        return;
    }
    
    expenseFormContainer.load(url);
})
```

Comment: *The problem with this is that I am not getting any client-side validation* - this will depend on your client-side validation.  It's likely that it initiates on doc.ready - you have two options - 1) using your existing code where the form is loaded dynamically, after the load make a call to the validation to reinitialise it.  2) load all the forms initially then show/hide them based on the drop down value (depends on the size of the forms)

Comment: @freedomn-m for option 1) how can I reinitialize the validation?

Comment: this will depend on your client-side validation